# VB.Net Formatting Output

Tags: vb.net, markup

I'm converting a project which started life as a PHP application to a Windows Forms Application in VB.Net, and am not sure how to go about formatting my output. The original, of course, simply outputs in HTML, and I've thought of using a WebBrowser control, but is there a better/more standard/any other way to display formatted output?

I'm new to Visual Studio, and Windows application programming in general. I've done a fair amount of work with VBA, so I'm familiar with the basics of the language, but still trying to figure out a lot of things. I think my question is beyond asking how to display output in VB.NET, as I'm familiar with the various form controls, such as label and textbox, but I googled extensively before posting here, and could not find what I was looking for. VB tutorials I've found are along the lines of "A variable is...." which I don't need. [This site](http://www.visual-basic-tutorials.com/), while pretty basic, does have some interesting stuff, and is where I came across the WebBrowser control, but I'm just wondering if that's the best or only way to do what I want.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application?  A Windows forms application?  WPF?  Something else?  There are many ways to display output, and they differ by the technologies you're using and what you're trying to accomplish.  Currently you're essentially asking how to display output in VB.NET, which would generally be answered by starting with a tutorial on whatever technology you're using.

Comment: @David Sorry I wasn't clear. I've added more information to the question.

Comment: I think a [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) could be handy for such an output. However, if you are just starting with your application, you might look into WPF, it has quite some controls which could be handy for you

Comment: First make sure the data you posted is not real personal data. If it is real data then try replacing it with a mock data/screen.